# update seekbar using edittext and decimal numbers

Tags: java, android, eclipse

ok let me explain:

i have a seekbar and a edittextbox, the seekbar only goes from 0 to 100, when the user used the seekbar and advance in the editbox it also show the progress, if the user input a number from 0 to 100 the seekbar automatically updates to the number in the edit textbox.

here is  the code:

```
EditText num1;
SeekBar Sb1;
num1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.hoja1E2);
Sb1=(SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
Sb1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
        {
        }
        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
        {
        }
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
        boolean fromUser)
        {
        //---change the font size of the EditText---

            num1.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
        }
        });

        num1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            try{
                //Update Seekbar value after entering a number
            Sb1.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(s.toString()));
            num1.setSelection(num1.getText().length());

            } catch(Exception ex) {}
        }
            });
```

now my problem is i whant to do the same thing but this time the bar only goes from o to 1, i change a part of the code of the seekbar where i divide the progress whit 100 this way it show in the edittextbox decimal number, but i cant figure out how to introduce decimal number and update the seekbar if some can help my

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
int progress = Math.round(Float.parseFloat(s.toString()) * 100f);
Sb1.setProgress(progress);
```

NOTE: You need to do a lot of validation

Comment: Can you please tell me why isn't mine working... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20802397/change-seekbar-progress-based-on-edittext-value